# Recreation of Main Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences, application-settings, recreate

I have a main `Activity` which contains of approximately 90 percent of my app `Fragments`. After user, logged in on login activity I add the main fragment on `onCreate()` of the Master Activity.

The issue is when in `SettingFragment` (which is a `PreferenceFragment`) i change the locale of the app , I have to recreate the main `Activity` so on `onCreate()` it loads the main fragment again which is not desirable (I want to remain on setting with new language).

What is the best way to handle such situation? I have thought of checking `SettingFragment` visibility from `FragmentManager` but on recreation it cannot find the settingFragment and it returns always null. Another way might be writing on `sharedPreferences` to check if MainFragment loaded or not but I am not sure of what's the best state to write or read to.

Comment: You should use SharedPreferences for simple things like flags. Check this [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) with all your options and you'll see why. BTW if no one else writes an answer to your question, you can do so and, after a while, accept it.

Comment: Proper formatting of the question helps readability and increases chances of a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add `android:configChanges="locale"` to your activity, then on you fragments you need to overwrite and refresh your UI.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  // refresh your views here
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```